# Spring Cloud Streams RabbitMQ multi-binder vs the Shovel Plugin/Application

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

Let's consider two systems.
Each of the systems uses a dedicated messaging broker for communication between its micro-services.

We want to communicate these two systems using Spring Cloud Stream.

#### Case A

Both the systems use RabbitMQ as a message broker.

Which approach is better:

1. **Multi-binder** (`spring.cloud.stream.binders`) allows connecting to two different administrative domains. "Multi-binder configuration the `environment.spring.rabbitmq` forces us to create a whole new child application context which doesn't take into account any application configured beans"... that causes [some issues](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1541)
2. **[Shovel Plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html)** that moves messages between two different administrative domains and doesn't force the system to go outside its domain. Is the Shovel Plugin production ready?

#### Case B

The first system uses RabbitMQ and the second uses Kafka message broker.

Which approach is better:

1. **Multi-binder** - analogously to the Case A.1.
2. **Shovel Integration App** implemented as a Spring Cloud Stream multi-binder, that works like the multi-broker Shovel Plugin. In this case, our system isn't forced to go outside its domain.

I think that the A.2 and B.2 are the better solutions, but I would like to discuss this with experienced software developers.

Comment: Ideally I'd say A1, but as you pointed out we have issue with some of the advanced configurations. Those need to be fixed before A1 becomes a viable option. So, with that I'd err on the side of A2.

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky What about `loose coupling`? Multi-binder makes difficult to upgrade shared messaging broker system, Shovel plugin makes it easier.

Comment: "Multi-binder makes difficult. . ." - in what way? I mean yes you'd need to upgrade some properties etc., but how often do you swap your system from one broker to another? The key IMHO is that the functional code would not change.

Now, that doesn't mean that Shovel plugin is not a viable option and in fact appears to be the only option you can use at the moment to avoid multiple binders. . .

Comment: Multi-binder makes difficult to upgrade shared messaging broker system because you have to take care that all clients are ready to work with the new version. In the case of shovel plugin you have to check plugin compatibility only.